# Why is this liveview mounting again after being redirected to a non-liveview page?

Tags: authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I'm working in a project that is mostly a freshly generated web app from `phx.new` and `phx.gen.auth`. I have an index page that is non-liveview. After login, the user is redirected to the main page, which is a liveview.

*The expectation:* After clicking the generated `Log out` link, the user should be redirected to the `/` index page, which is not a liveview. This behavior is specified by the generated authentication.

*The experience:* The problem is that when I click the generated `Log out` link, instead of being redirected to the logged out index splash page, as the generated authentication is written to do, instead I'm redirected to the login page, where I see two flash messages: one `:info` flash indicating successful logout, and a second `:error` flash complaining ""You must be logged in to access this page." I don't want users to see that `:error` flash on the login page, and worse, I think, is the fact that the reason that `:error` flash is appearing is because the `PageLive` liveview, which is not present on the index page, is running its `mount/3` function again (a third time), which is causing the liveview authentication to run again, and cause a second redirect. Importantly, this issue occurs *intermittently*, i.e. sometimes the redirect works correctly and sends the user to the index page without issue, and other times the second, redundant redirect and the mistaken flash message is displayed. I think this indicates some kind of race condition.

I have a relatively newly generated project with these routes (among others):

`router.ex`

```elixir
  scope "/", MyappWeb do
    pipe_through :browser

    live_session :default do
      live "/dash", PageLive, :index
    end
  end

  scope "/", MyappWeb do
    pipe_through [:browser, :redirect_if_user_is_authenticated]

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  scope "/", MyappWeb do
    pipe_through [:browser]

    delete "/users/log_out", UserSessionController, :delete
  end
```

The authentication was generated by `phx.gen.auth`. The `delete` action in the generated `UserSessionController` triggers the generated `UserAuth.log_out_user/1` to fire.

`user_session_controller.ex`

```elixir
  def delete(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Logged out successfully.")
    |> UserAuth.log_out_user()
  end
```

`user_auth.ex`

```elixir
  def log_out_user(conn) do
    user_token = get_session(conn, :user_token)
    user_token && Accounts.delete_session_token(user_token)

    if live_socket_id = get_session(conn, :live_socket_id) do
      MyappWeb.Endpoint.broadcast(live_socket_id, "disconnect", %{})
    end

    conn
    |> renew_session()
    |> delete_resp_cookie(@remember_me_cookie)
    |> redirect(to: "/")
  end
```

The live route in the router to `/dash` routes through a liveview called `PageLive`, which simply mounts over some authentication, as recommended in [liveview docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/security-model.html#mounting-considerations):

`page_live.ex`

```elixir
defmodule MyappWeb.PageLive do
  use MyappWeb, :live_view
  alias MyappWeb.Live.Components.PackageSearch
  alias MyappWeb.Live.Components.Tabs
  alias MyappWeb.Live.Components.Tabs.TabItem
  on_mount MyappWeb.UserLiveAuth
end
```

`user_live_auth.ex`

```elixir
defmodule MyappWeb.UserLiveAuth do
  import Phoenix.LiveView, only: [assign_new: 3, redirect: 2]
  alias Myapp.Accounts
  alias Myapp.Accounts.User
  alias MyappWeb.Router.Helpers, as: Routes

  def mount(_params, session, socket) do
    socket =
      assign_new(socket, :current_user, fn ->
        find_current_user(session)
      end)

    case socket.assigns.current_user do
      %User{} ->
        {:cont, socket}

      _ ->
        socket =
          socket
          |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in to access this page.")
          |> redirect(to: Routes.user_session_path(socket, :new))

        {:halt, socket}
    end
  end

  defp find_current_user(session) do
    with user_token when not is_nil(user_token) <- session["user_token"],
         %User{} = user <- Accounts.get_user_by_session_token(user_token),
         do: user
  end
end
```

Here's the log of the process after the user clicks log out:

```
**[info] POST /users/log_out**
[debug] Processing with MyappWeb.UserSessionController.delete/2
  Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "ET8xMSU5KSEedycKEAcJfX0JCl45LmcF_VEHANhinNqHcaz6MFRkIqWu", "_method" => "delete"}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[debug] QUERY OK source="users_tokens" db=1.8ms idle=389.7ms
SELECT u1."id", u1."email", u1."hashed_password", u1."confirmed_at", u1."first_name", u1."last_name", u1."username", u1."inserted_at", u1."updated_at" FROM "users_tokens" AS u0 INNER JOIN "users" AS u1 ON u1."id" = u0."user_id" WHERE ((u0."token" = $1) AND (u0."context" = $2)) AND (u0."inserted_at" > $3::timestamp + (-(60)::numeric * interval '1 day')) [<<159, 144, 113, 83, 223, 12, 183, 119, 50, 248, 83, 234, 128, 237, 129, 112, 138, 147, 148, 100, 67, 163, 50, 244, 127, 26, 254, 184, 102, 74, 11, 52>>, "session", ~U[2021-10-06 22:13:44.080128Z]]
[debug] QUERY OK source="users_tokens" db=1.7ms idle=391.8ms
DELETE FROM "users_tokens" AS u0 WHERE ((u0."token" = $1) AND (u0."context" = $2)) [<<159, 144, 113, 83, 223, 12, 183, 119, 50, 248, 83, 234, 128, 237, 129, 112, 138, 147, 148, 100, 67, 163, 50, 244, 127, 26, 254, 184, 102, 74, 11, 52>>, "session"]
**[info] Sent 302 in 6ms**
**[info] CONNECTED TO Phoenix.LiveView.Socket in 64µs
  Transport: :websocket
  Serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer
  Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" =>** "ET8xMSU5KSEedycKEAcJfX0JCl45LmcF_VEHANhinNqHcaz6MFRkIqWu", "_mounts" => "0", "_track_static" => %{"0" => "http://localhost:4000/assets/app.css", "1" => "http://localhost:4000/assets/app.js"}, "vsn" => "2.0.0"}
[debug] QUERY OK source="users_tokens" db=1.6ms idle=422.5ms
SELECT u1."id", u1."email", u1."hashed_password", u1."confirmed_at", u1."first_name", u1."last_name", u1."username", u1."inserted_at", u1."updated_at" FROM "users_tokens" AS u0 INNER JOIN "users" AS u1 ON u1."id" = u0."user_id" WHERE ((u0."token" = $1) AND (u0."context" = $2)) AND (u0."inserted_at" > $3::timestamp + (-(60)::numeric * interval '1 day')) [<<159, 144, 113, 83, 223, 12, 183, 119, 50, 248, 83, 234, 128, 237, 129, 112, 138, 147, 148, 100, 67, 163, 50, 244, 127, 26, 254, 184, 102, 74, 11, 52>>, "session", ~U[2021-10-06 22:13:44.110158Z]]
**[info] GET /users/log_in**
[debug] Processing with MyappWeb.UserSessionController.new/2
  Parameters: %{}
  Pipelines: [:browser, :redirect_if_user_is_authenticated]
[info] Sent 200 in 6ms
```

Notice how in the logs above, the 302 redirect occurs, and then immediately the socket reconnects and `mount/3` runs, which then triggers another redirect, this time to the `/users/log_in` route. As far as I understand, the socket should not be trying to reconnect here, and I can't see what's triggering this.

Why is the `PageLive` mount being triggered again after the 302 redirect to a non-liveview page upon logout, thus triggering a second redirect to the login page?

Comment: What does your "Log out" link/button look like (in the html.heex file)?

Comment: `<li><%= link "Log out", to: Routes.user_session_path(@conn, :delete), method: :delete %></li>`

Comment: Because of the redirect behaviour, my first suspect would be redirect_if_user_is_authenticated.

Comment: @randyr I thought that might be the case too, but after some observation I saw that the `:redirect_if_user_is_authenticated` function is never run at all, because the browser is never requests `/` after the redirect, and thus the `redirect_if_user_is_authenticed` plug in the `:browser` pipeline never runs. I just added the server log output to the question

Answer (score 0):

They key is this code

```elixir
MyappWeb.Endpoint.broadcast(live_socket_id, "disconnect", %{})
```

in `log_out_user/1`. Here you disconnect the live view socket via an Erlang message.

This triggers the socket to shutdown server side (see [Phoenix.Socket](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.6.0/lib/phoenix/socket.ex#L482-L484))

```elixir
def __info__(%Broadcast{event: "disconnect"}, state) do
  {:stop, {:shutdown, :disconnected}, state}
end
```

But then it is a live view, which will reconnect after a disconnect happened via client side javascript and then remount the live view, which causes `MyappWeb.UserLiveAuth` to add the flash message again.

For reference, [check the LiveView docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/security-model.html#disconnecting-all-instances-of-a-live-user):

> Once a LiveView is disconnected, the client will attempt to reestablish the connection and re-execute the mount/3 callback. In this case, if the user is no longer logged in or it no longer has access to the current resource, mount/3 will fail and the user will be redirected.

A potential solution could be, to do the flash + redirect already in a plug inside of the routing pipeline instead of the mount, so non logged in users will be redirected when loading the page, and then just `{:halt, socket}` in the live view mount, so there is no redirect on logout. Or alternatively send the broadcast for disconnecting after the logout request has already redirected (maybe spinning off an async `Task` could help).

So maybe wrap the broadcast like this, to make the browser close the liveview itself (while still redirecting all other open live views):

```elixir
Task.async(fn -> 
  :timer.sleep(1000) # Give the browser some time to process the response and close the LV
  MyappWeb.Endpoint.broadcast(live_socket_id, "disconnect", %{})
end)
```

Comment: Strangely enough, you can comment out the broadcast line `MyappWeb.Endpoint.broadcast(live_socket_id, "disconnect", %{})` in `log_out_user/1`, and the same unwanted behavior occurs intermittently. Which unfortunately must mean that this isn't what's triggering the client side to try to reconnect.

Comment: I attempted the async call to broadcast just in case, and unfortunately the same unwanted behavior intermittently occurs.

Comment: Have you ever tried changing the flash message in `UserLiveAuth.mount` call, to be sure the flash even comes from there?

Comment: Thank you, yes I did. It's definitely coming from there. In fact, my workaround at the moment is to just remove the flash, because otherwise the behavior would appear normal to the user.

Answer (score 0):

In `user_auth.ex`, I have these lines, which delete the user session from the db:

```
  def log_out_user(conn) do
    user_token = get_session(conn, :user_token)
    user_token && Accounts.delete_session_token(user_token)
```

The reason the problem is occurring is because the live mount is failing authentication, since the session token no longer exists in the database. This triggers a redirect before the regular `UserAuth.log)out_user/1` redirect has a chance to fire.

Inspired by @smallbutton's solution, I'm using ensuring that the session token is not deleted until after the `log_out_user/1` redirect to avoid the race condition:

```
  def log_out_user(conn) do
    if live_socket_id = get_session(conn, :live_socket_id) do
      MyAppWeb.Endpoint.broadcast(live_socket_id, "disconnect", %{})
    end

    # TODO is there a better way to handle this issue?
    Task.async(fn ->
      :timer.sleep(1000)
      user_token = get_session(conn, :user_token)
      user_token && Accounts.delete_session_token(user_token)
    end)

    conn
    |> renew_session()
    |> delete_resp_cookie(@remember_me_cookie)
    |> redirect(to: "/")
  end
```

This is an unsatisfying workaround though, because I don't like to have to manually coordinate events like this.